# d3 foreignObjects, adding checkbox and text from data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Appending an html checkbox and text with foreign objects.

```
.attr("id",function(d){return d.id;})
        .append("foreignObject")
          .attr("width", 200)
          .attr("height", 200)
          .attr("x",0)
          .attr("y",0)
          .append("xhtml:body")
          .html("<form><input type=checkbox id=check class=tick/></form>")
```

The code above works, but if I try to put a span/label along with the checkbox, that works too but only if with plain text values. I want to do the label dynamically from the data like below

```
html("<form><input type=checkbox id=check class=tick/><span>"+function(d){return d.name;}+"</span></form>")
```

But it doesn't evaluate the function and outputs the text "function(d){return d.name;}" as the label. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass html() a function or a string, not a string concatenated with a function.  This should work:

```
.html(function(d) {return "<form><input type=checkbox id=check class=tick/><span>" + d.name + "</span></form>";})
```